# How to set directory-property comments

Tags: powershell, explorer

I'm trying to find a way to set comments with powershell for a directory.
[image]

How can I set for a folder comments (like contains contact files)?
Thanks for infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite interesting question so i quickly did a bit of research. It is not as trivial as one would hope. In fact at least on W10 its basically impossible to do it via UI but i found a way to do it with Powershell:

First you have to make the Folder a system folder (somehow comments are only shown on system folders on my machine, got to test on yours yourself):

```
attrib +s <Folderpath>
```

Not sure if we can do it with a cmdlet (probably but no time to research right now).

Then you have to create a "Desktop.ini" file inside the folder like so:

```
"[.ShellClassInfo]","Infotip=YOUR COMMENT HERE"|Out-File <Folderpath>\Desktop.ini
```

and thats basically it :)